# Migrate VUE 2 SSR template interpolation with <!--vue-ssr-outlet--> to VUE 3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, server-side-rendering

Vue 2->3 migration guide https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/ is very poor and does not explain many situations available in VUE 2. For example in VUE 2 by this doc https://v2.ssr.vuejs.org/guide/#using-a-page-template (`Using a Page Template`) we can do...

**index.template.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- use double mustache for HTML-escaped interpolation -->
    <title>{{ title }}</title>

    <!-- use triple mustache for non-HTML-escaped interpolation -->
    {{{ meta }}}
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--vue-ssr-outlet-->
  </body>
</html>
```

**node-test-vue2.js**

```js
const Vue = require('vue'); // VUE 2

const template = require('fs').readFileSync('./index.template.html', 'utf-8');

const renderer = require('vue-server-renderer').createRenderer({
  template,
});

const context = {
    title: 'vue ssr',
    meta: `
        <meta name="keyword" content="vue,ssr">
        <meta name="description" content="vue srr demo">
    `,
};

const options = {
  data: {
    date: new Date()
  },
  template: `<div>The date is: {{ date }}</div>`,
};

const app = new Vue(options);

const html = await renderer.renderToString(app, context);
console.log(html);
```

VUE 3 `require('@vue/runtime-core').createRenderer()` https://vuejs.org/api/custom-renderer.html#createrenderer does not have `template` option at all. How to migrate code above to VUE 3? VUE 3 SSR doc just show very simple example https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/ssr.html#rendering-an-app with adding template `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>...` manually without any template interpolation example.

**node-test-vue3.js**

```js
// note: for consts "template", "options" and "context" see node-test-vue2.js

// template option does not exists / does not work on line below
const renderer = await require('@vue/runtime-core').createRenderer({ template });

const app = renderer.createApp(options);
var html = await renderer.renderToString(app, context);
console.log(html);
```